# Counting cells per Date

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, date

I have a database of hotel rooms availability by date. Each day some hotels were available (Availablity = T) and some were not (Availablity = F).
I am looking for a way to count the number of Trues and Falses per date.
Initially, the dataframe looks like this:

```
Room ID   Date    Availablity 
112      1/1/19       T
112      2/1/19       F
112      3/1/19       F
113      1/1/19       F
113      2/1/19       T
114      1/1/19       T
```

I want to count the number of times each date has the value of True and False and then to make a plot of occupancy per data over the year.
Namely, a datefarme that looks like this:

```
Date     num of Ts    num of Fs
1/1/19      #             #
2/1/19      #             #
3/1/19      #             #
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `dcast` seems farily elegant here: `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df1), Date ~ Availablity)`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `table` after subsetting the 'Date', and 'Availability' column.  It would get the count of `FALSE/TRUE` from 'Availability' for each unique 'Date'

```
table(df1[-1])
```

---

Or in a `tbl_df/data.frame` format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   count(Date, Availablity) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Availablity, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

which is similar to

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>%
   summarise(num_of_false = sum(!Availablity), num_of_true = sum(Availablity))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(RoomID = c(112L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 113L, 114L), 
    Date = c("1/1/19", "2/1/19", "3/1/19", "1/1/19", "2/1/19", 
    "1/1/19"), Availablity = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: But the dates are not unique. There are many same dates for different Room IDs

Comment: @RonSlavaGrodko  This is based on your example and as you haven't showed the expected output numbers, it is not clear

Comment: @RonSlavaGrodko  Your description is  `am looking for a way to count the number of Trues and Falses per date.`  The code is doing that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate()` from base R to make it

```
dfout <- aggregate(Availablity ~ Date,df,function(x) setNames(cbind(sum(!x),sum(x)),c("num_Ts","num_Fs")))
```

such that

```
> dfout
    Date Availablity.num_Ts Availablity.num_Fs
1 1/1/19                  1                  2
2 2/1/19                  1                  1
3 3/1/19                  1                  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Availablity~RoomID+Date, df, function(x) 
    c(count_true = sum(as.logical(x)), count_false = sum(!as.logical(x))))
```